# Linker multiple definition error: Why does <thread> seem to define my functions?

Tags: c++, linker, multiple-definition-error

When building my project, I'm getting the following error message. Unfortunately I can't make any sense of it.

```
CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx/send_dummy_events.cc.o: In function `std::chrono::duration_values<long>::zero()':
/usr/include/c++/6/thread:311: multiple definition of `POLONAISE::xxx::dispatch_event(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx/main.cc.o:/home/manuel/projects/projectname/build_x86_64/package/xxx/send_dummy_events.cc:10: first defined here

CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx/send_dummy_events.cc.o: In function `std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >::count() const':
/usr/include/c++/6/thread:311: multiple definition of `POLONAISE::xxx::send_dummy_events()'
CMakeFiles/xxx.dir/xxx/main.cc.o:/home/manuel/projects/projectname/build_x86_64/package/xxx/send_dummy_events.cc:16: first defined here
```

To me, this seems as `/usr/include/c++/6/thread` would re-define my function names `dispatch_event()` and `send_dummy-event()`.

The source of my `send_dummy_events.cc` is this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "POLONAISE/logging.h"
#include "POLONAISE/EventQueue.h"


namespace POLONAISE {
    namespace xxx {
        void dispatch_event(std::string serialized_uirequest __attribute__((unused)))
        {

        }           


        void send_dummy_events()
        {
            std::chrono::seconds delay(3);
            while (1) {
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The source of `usr/include/c++/6/thread` is this: (Don't be confused by the line numbers, I forgot how to turn them off in Vim.)

```
     /// sleep_for
  2     template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  1       inline void
311       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
  1       {
  2         if (__rtime <= __rtime.zero())
  3           return;
  4         auto __s = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(__rtime);
  5         auto __ns = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(__rtime - __s);
  6 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
  7         __gthread_time_t __ts =
  8           {
  9             static_cast<std::time_t>(__s.count()),
 10             static_cast<long>(__ns.count())
 11           };
 12         while (::nanosleep(&__ts, &__ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
 13           { }
 14 #else
 15         __sleep_for(__s, __ns);
 16 #endif
 17       }
```

Comment: multiple definition errors normally means you have code defined in a header file that does not have include guards or you are including a source file in another file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Include guards doesn't help if the header file is included in different source files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude True, but it doesn't hurt to have them in case they are included up the chain without realizing they are.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if it's included in different source file, shouldn't it be fine since there is no redefinition?

Comment: @CIsForCookies If you define a function with the same name in two source files, create object files from those two source files, and then link the object files together you would have the same symbol defined in two [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) which is what gives linker-errors like multiple definition. That the function (or any other symbol) comes from a header file doesn't matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so, if A.c and B.c both include H.h which defines 'void foo()' and then link objects O_a and O_b the linker would not understand that 'foo' in *O_a* is the same as 'foo' *n O_b*?

Comment: @CIsForCookies That's correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I learned that I caused the problem by not following what I became to know a basic programming rule. Thanks for all your comments, they were very enlightening nonetheless! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason and am now answering my own question:

The root cause was, that in `main.cc` I `#include`d `send_dummy_events.cc`. As this was just a temporary test stub, I didn't saw any problem in that a few weeks ago. But now I duplicated my existing code for a new part of the application, and when updating the `CMakeLists.txt`, I just made sure that every source files is noted there. So I added `send_dummy_events.cc`.

Voilà, as the linker now got the same symbols twice, he rightly complained about it.

Now I heard that there's even a rule about this: *Never include source files.* Well, know I know why.

I'm still confused by why the error message reads as if the second defintion would occur in `/usr/include/c++/6/thread`, but I guess that's just another "confusing error message™" GCC is known for.